# using rsync include exclude patterns matches whitespace

Tags: rsync, trailing-whitespace

i've encountering problems when I use `rsync` (v3.2.3 on a Pi with Raspbian) with directories containing a whitespace at the end. example:

```
pi:~ $ find source/
source/
source/hello
source/hello/whitespace_dir  <--- dir with whitespace at the end
source/hello/whitespace_file <--- file with whitespace at the end
source/foo
source/foo/bar1
source/foo/bar2
```

output of a dry run rsync:

```
pi:~ $ rsync -aHv --dry-run --include="*/" --include="bar" --exclude="*" source/ target/
sending incremental file list
./
foo/
foo/bar1/
foo/bar2/
hello/
hello/whitespace_dir /
```

The -vvv explanation says

```
[sender] hiding file hello/whitespace_file  because of pattern *
[sender] pushing local filters for /home/pi/source/hello/whitespace_dir /
```

Why? I just want to copy all dir's AND files matching the pattern "bar".

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
rsync -rmv --dry-run --include="*/" --include="*/*bar*" --exclude="*" source/ target/
```

will give you what you want.

rsync will not report files unless your include **regex** pattern covers the conditions to match the desired files.

**Note** rsync logic to pass information for all levels of parent directories to reach the identified files, not just the fullpath of the files themselves.